# Steam: Convert SteamID64 to SteamID using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, steam, steam-web-api

How would someone convert steamid64 (example: 76561198074259974) into a steamid (STEAM_0:0:56997123) using PHP/javascript (I would like to display a steamid on a loading screen, but not the steamid64)

Comment: Check out this documentation on the API [Steam API Documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the code here for converting steamID to steamID64: https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=60899?t=60899

You can reverse it for converting steamID64 to steamID, for this the formula would be:
    (steamID64 - (76561197960265728 + (steamID64 % 2)))/2

This would give you the numbers after the second colon (:). If steamID64 is odd (steamID64 % 2) the number after the first colon would be 1 otherwise a 0.

Comment: I figured it out, however thank you for the answer my solution was different however:

 http://pastebin.com/aypuL93t